# Getting datestamp in known format

Tags: string, datetime, dm-script

As far as I can tell the following functions are what is available and they all depend on the date/time settings of the system:

```
GetTime()
GetDate()
DateStamp()
GetCurrentTime().FormatTimeString()
```

This makes for pretty timestamps in the result window but is really problematic for putting timestamps into filenames. Is there a command that will get me the date and time in a system-independent format, or do I need to write some crazy function to do it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the commands availble from the help documentation, section "Utility Functions" ? In particular the parameters for

`String FormatTimeString( Number time, Number format )`

[image]

Or if you want to construct something "crazy" this might be helpful:

`void DeconstructLocalGregorianDate( Number time, NumberVariable year, NumberVariable month, NumberVariable day, NumberVariable hour, NumberVariable minute, NumberVariable second, NumberVariable nanosecond )`

You can use it like in the following example:

[image]

```
Number year, month, day 
Number hour, minute, second, nanosecond 
GetCurrentTime().DeconstructLocalGregorianDate( year, month, day, hour, minute, second, nanosecond )
string myFormat = year+"_"+month+"_"+day+"--"+hour+"-"+minute+"-"+second
OKDialog( myFormat )
```

Comment: I did a for loop with 0 through 255 as the argument yes, and it seems all of them follows the system settings. It is when documentation, handbook and creativity runs out that I come here ;) But now that you say it the deconstruct function does seem to make the "crazy" solution rather easy. Thanks again :)